SQL Express CPU limitation ignored
I have a SQL Express 2014 running on a VM with 12 cores

SQL Express limitations state that it should be limited to either 4 cores or 1 socket, but when I run this query:

select count(1) "Nb Core used" from sys.dm_os_schedulers where status = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'

it returns 8...

Here's the result of the query as asked in the comments (Please note that there is no column "socket_count" on that DMV for SQL2014

And here are the information about Core/Socket at OS level:

How could that be ?
Thank you

It seems like Hyper-threading does not count, so that would explain why I can see 8 scheduler on a SQL Express server:

The use of hyper-threading technology does not affect the number of core licenses required when running SQL Server software in a physical OSE.

From : Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Licensing guide  <
Thank you Aleksey Vitsko for putting me on the right track.
